# I can't download files using selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm using selenium actually, and I need to get the files that can be downloaded using

```
driver.get_downloadable_files(),
```

but I'm getting the following error :

```
Exception has occurred: WebDriverException
Message: You must enable downloads in order to work with downloadable files.
  File "/Users/abderrahim/Documents/alertes_aggregator/utils/profile_extractor.py", line 81, in linkedin_profile
    pdf = driver.get_downloadable_files()*
```

Is there any solution to this ? knowing that I've already added the experimental options :

```
options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")
    options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
        "download.default_directory": r"/Users/abderrahim/Documents/cv_apec",
        "download.prompt_for_download": False
        })
```

I tried severals solution, but none seems to work, any suggestions ?

Answer (score -1):

checking the docs of selenium [here](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/drivers/remote_webdriver/?tab=python#list-downloadable-files)

says for **downloads**:

Enable Downloads in the Grid
**Regardless** of the client, when starting the grid in node or standalone mode, you must add the flag:

```
--enable-managed-downloads true
```

Enable Downloads in the Client
The grid uses the se:downloadsEnabled capability to toggle whether to be responsible for managing the browser location. Each of the bindings have a method in the options class to set this.

for python :

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.enable_downloads = True
driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor=server, options=options)
```

then you list like this

```
files = driver.get_downloadable_files()
```

then to download

```
driver.download_file(downloadable_file, target_directory)
```

for full example on guthub for the downloading part from selenium docs check [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/seleniumhq.github.io/blob/trunk/examples/python/tests/drivers/test_remote_webdriver.py#L47)

Answer (score -1):

That seems like a lot of code, while the custom settings aren't generic and only work on Chromium-based browsers. This is one of the reason why I created the [Browserist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/) package as an extension to Selenium so you don't have to hassle with the settings and other details (for instance, downlads are already enabled by default).

Find more information about [methods to download files in the documentation](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/user-guide/download-files/#methods).

Maybe something like this would work?

```py
from browserist import Browser, BrowserSettings

settings = BrowserSettings(
    download_dir="/Users/abderrahim/Documents/cv_apec"
)

with Browser(settings) as browser:
    browser.open.url("https://example.com")
    pdf_file_path = browser.click.download_and_get_file_path("//xpath/to/pdf/link")
    print(pdf_file_path.absolute())
```

The expected output would be something like this: `/Users/abderrahim/Documents/cv_apec/file.pdf`

And if you prefer working directly with the Selenium WebDriver after initiating the browser settings, you can always do something like this:

```py
from browserist import Browser, BrowserSettings

settings = BrowserSettings(
    download_dir="/Users/abderrahim/Documents/cv_apec"
)

with Browser(settings) as browser:
    driver = browser.driver
    driver.get_downloadable_files()
```

In full disclosure, I'm the author of the [Browserist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/) package. [Browserist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/) is lightweight, less verbose extension of the Selenium web driver that makes browser automation even easier.

Simply install the package with `pip install browserist` and you're ready to go.